# I'm trying to make a square appear using a delayed timer but it's not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my stylesheet and code:

```
.shape{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#DD0A19;
  display:none;
}
```

I am trying to make a game that tests users' reaction times to clicking the square, which disappears when clicked.

```
<body>
  <p>Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
  <div class="shape" id="disappear"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var start = new Date().getTime();

  function makeItemAppear () {
    document.getElementById("disappear").style.display = "block";
    start = new Date().getTime();
  }

  function appearAfterDelay () {
    set.Timeout(makeItemAppear, 1000);
  }

  appearAfterDelay();

  document.getElementById('disappear').onclick = function  () {
    document.getElementById("disappear").style.display = "none";
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var timeTaken = (end - start)/1000;
    document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
    appearAfterDelay();

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just delete the dot - '.' in set.timeout .

```
set.Timeout --> setTimeout
```

Answer (score 1):

change :

```
function appearAfterDelay () {
set.Timeout(makeItemAppear, 1000);
}
```

to :

```
function appearAfterDelay () {
            setTimeout(makeItemAppear, 1000);
        }
```

final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .shape{
                    height:200px;
                    width:200px;
                    background-color:#DD0A19;
                    display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
        <div class="shape" id="disappear"></div>
        
        <script>
            var start = new Date().getTime();

            function makeItemAppear () {
                document.getElementById("disappear").style.display = "block";
                start = new Date().getTime();
            }

            function appearAfterDelay () {
            setTimeout(makeItemAppear, 1000);
        }

            appearAfterDelay();

            document.getElementById('disappear').onclick = function  () {
                document.getElementById("disappear").style.display = "none";
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                var timeTaken = (end - start)/1000;
                document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
                appearAfterDelay();

            }
           
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set.Timeout is not a function. This is getting the Timeout attribute of the object set which does not exist.

SetTimeout is a built in function, not an object so your going to want to change

```
set.Timeout(makeItemAppear, 1000)
```

to

```
setTimeout(makeItemAppear,1000)
```